# (NextJS 13) Unhandled Runtime Error when adding custom component

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack, next.js

**Problem:**
I am currently working on a nextjs portfolio website and i get an error when including a custom component in the layout.jsx file.

**The error:**
Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: Unsupported Server Component type: undefined

- error Error: Unsupported Server Component type: undefined
  at stringify ()
  digest: "1926456981"

**The code:**

- Navbar.jsx:

```
import Link from 'next/link'
const Navbar = ()=>{
  return(
      <nav>
        <Link href="/">Home</Link>
        <Link href="/contact">Contact</Link>
        <Link href="/projects">Projects</Link>
        <Link href="/links">Links</Link>
        <Link href="/certs">Certs</Link>
      </nav>
  );
}
export default Navbar;
```

- layout.jsx:

```
import "./globals.css";
import { Inter } from "next/font/google";
import { Navbar } from "../components/Navbar";

const inter = Inter({
  subsets: ["latin"],
});

export const metadata = {
  title: "Stevan's Portfolio",
  description: "Generated by create next app",
};

export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={inter.className}>
        <header>
          <Navbar />
        </header>
        {children}
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

- I have tried to just create a new project.
- I have tried to check the path.
- I have tried to add "use client".
  _ etc...

Comment: remove curly brackets import Navbar from "../components/Navbar"